# graph api: How Can I access or delete subscriptions form created by other users /applications?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription

Sending **Get Request for subscription** (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions) there are following results:

- Requesting with application permissions I **only** got the subscription which are created by the application.
- Requesting with a delegateToken ( where user  is an admin) I get all subscription of user and apps listed. (permission subscrptions.read.all must be set then it worked)

But accessing an subcriptions *([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/%7Bid%7D)* for show, update or delete it works only for the the subscriptions created by the the admin user.

if I try to access other subcription with a get Request, I got this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Read; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-09-07T13:01:15",
            "request-id": "f7ddf8bd-562d-487b-bde0-d64b25fd78a8",
            "client-request-id": "8806f229-e11d-491f-94f5-207bd0f7103a"
        }
```

Is there a way to access (show, update, delete)  other subscriptions, which are not created by the user (the user has admin rights)?
is that possible ?
And if so what must done additional? Adding some special roles?
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, an application wants to retrieve subscriptions that it originally created for the currently signed-in user, or for all users in the directory (work/school accounts). These scenarios do not require any special permissions beyond the ones the app used originally to create its subscriptions.

[image]

In some cases, an app wants to retrieve subscriptions created by other apps. For example, a user wants to see all subscriptions created by any app on their behalf. Or, an administrator may want to see all subscriptions from all apps in their directory. For such scenarios, a **delegated permission Subscription.Read.All** is required.

[image]

Refer below documentation links for supported permissions.

[Get Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

[Update Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

[Delete Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Additional limitations apply for subscriptions on Outlook items. The limitations apply to creating as well as managing (getting, updating, and deleting) subscriptions. Delegated permission supports subscribing to items in folders in only the signed-in user's mailbox. For example, you cannot use the delegated permission Calendars.Read to subscribe to events in another user’s mailbox.

Similarly,additional limitations apply for subscriptions on OneDrive items. The limitations apply to creating as well as managing (getting, updating, and deleting) subscriptions.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#driveitem) for more details.

Thanks.

Comment: I read that to what you wrote described as Advanced Scenario . I wrote it at my 3 sentence **Requesting with a delegateToken ( admin user) I get all subscription of user and apps listed. (permission subscrptions.read.all must be set then it worked) ** But this only works list subscription, I tried it in aanother case i have a delegate token and the user admin and has the needed permissions, so it worked as described in list subscription but not for access of a single subscription from the json list. If I read it again the access scenario is only written for list subscription. –

Comment: if somene has other proposals to access foreign subscription with an admin account, plase write it. 
The solution must not Graph APi with c# or direct Http-request. 
If it will not work on some circumstances so, and e.g. Powershell can solve it  different. Every solution where I can access foreign subscription will be fine.
I will not handle a mass of user or app for accessing only  there own subscriptions.